# can we add on_click method on data of gridview?

Tags: c#, xml

am using C#, I recieved data from xml file and place it in gridview, is it possible to add on_click method on the rows in the gridview?? cause i want to make something like quick Access from data retrieved from xml file, kindly need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of events in gridView, you can see on the properties page. I can suggest you to use `CellDoubleClick` event as you want.

In the codebehind, you get indexes like this

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
 int columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
 int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
}
```

Comment: thanks i will try it, is there any tutorial website? and my cell are made dynamically depends on user login how can i deal with each row?

Comment: If you build your own DataTable, then you should know that which data storing in column index X,Y,Z...